# android:windowBackground doesn't work with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-theme

My layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I would like to apply theme dynamically from my Fragment
`requireContext().setTheme(R.style.MyTheme)`

Unfortunately, `android:windowBackground` doesn't set background on `RecyclerView`.

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient_background</item>
    </style>
```

Also, `android:background` doesn't work properly. It sets gradient background on every cell, not on the whole screen.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_background</item>
    </style>
```

Setting `android:background` on `RecyclerView` works

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

but I would like to achieve it by passing a single theme. Is it possible?

Comment: The question is not clear, please elaborate more what you're trying to do. From what you've said already, `android:windowBackground` is not an attribute on any views, including `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my question. Hope, it's better explained now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've used, you can create a custom attribute in your styles such as:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="recyclerViewBackground">@drawable/paywall_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme2" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="recyclerViewBackground">@drawable/another_background</item>
</style>
```

Add this to your **attrs.xml** file under **values** folder (if you don't have it, create it):

```
<attr name="recyclerViewBackground" format="reference" />
```

And set the background using this:

```
<com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyRecyclerView
    style="?theme"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="?recyclerViewBackground"/>
```

Changing the theme and **recreating the fragment** should change the background of the `RecyclerView` now. Also make sure every theme you will use with this view includes the attribute `recyclerViewBackground` otherwise you will get an exception.